# How to read contents from outputStream

Tags: java

How to read the contents from an OutputStream to a byte array or to an inputstream.

I have some data written to StreamingOutput and I need to read this data from another process.

Comment: You don't _read_ from an `OutputStream`, you _write_ to it.

Comment: Then wherever you're trying to read it from, you'll likely need an `InputStream` on that end

Answer (score 2):

You write to an output-stream and read from an input stream.
If you e.g. want a separate thread to write into an output-stream while another thread is reading that data from an input stream, you can use piped streams.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    PipedInputStream inputStream = new PipedInputStream();
    OutputStream outputStream = new PipedOutputStream(inputStream);

    executor.submit(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; ++c) {
                try {
                    IOUtils.write("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".getBytes(), outputStream);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // error
                } finally {
                    IOUtils.closeQuietly(outputStream);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    String string = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);
    System.out.println(string);
}
```

Be aware that this only works if you asynchronously read/write the data.

Comment: Thanks for the approach. However I cant change the way outputStream is written.

There is a process which writes to output stream in the below manner 
 outputStream.write(IOUtils.toByteArray(someContents)) [ I cant change the way this is written]

However I wish to read someContents in another another project.

Answer (score 2):

### Java IO Overview

The terms "input" and "output" can sometimes be a bit confusing. The input of one part of an application is often the output of another.

A program that needs to read data from some source needs an **InputStream** . A program that needs to write data to some destination needs an **OutputStream** .

An InputStream or Reader is linked to a source of data. An OutputStream or Writer is linked to a destination of data.

**Example Source Code**

```
package fileio;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class FileReadWrite {

    void writeToFile() throws IOException{
        byte[] data = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'};
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/Users/suparna/var/testfile.txt");
        try {
            output.write(data);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            output.close();
        }
    }

    void readFromFile() throws IOException{
        InputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream("/Users/suparna/var/testfile.txt");
        int data;
        try {
            data = inputstream.read();
            while(data != -1) {
                doSomethingWithData(data);
                data = inputstream.read();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            inputstream.close();
        }
    }

    private void doSomethingWithData(int data) {
        System.out.println(data);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileReadWrite rw = new FileReadWrite();
        try {
            rw.writeToFile();
            rw.readFromFile();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case, no file is involved.
There is a process which writes to output stream in the below manner 
 outputStream.write(IOUtils.toByteArray(someContents)) [ I cant change the way this is written]

However I wish to read someContents in another another project.

Comment: Are you using ByteArrayOutputStream? Also, are you referring to inter process communication using this mechanism? you mentioned two projects? are they same as two different JVM processes?

Comment: Yes..The content is converted to ByteArray before writting to the outputStream.

Comment: And are you talking about interprocess communication as well? How do you share the byte streams across two different JVM Processes?

Comment: Its like in one project the outputstream is getting written to and in other project i have to read the contents of it and do some operation on the data read.